# How to use loop to do different filters columns df combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

[image]

I have this function:

```py
def df_filter (df,col_key1,col_key2,col_key3,a,b,c):
   df1 = df[(df[col_key1]==a) & (df[col_key2]==b) & (df[col_key3]==c)
   df1  = df1.groupby(by=['ID'])['satisfaction'].mean()
   return df1

result_1 = df_filter (df,'key1','key2','key3',1,0,0)
result_2 = df_filter (df,'key1','key2','key3',1,1,0)
result_3 = df_filter (df,'key1','key2','key3',1,1,1)
result_4 = df_filter (df,'key1','key2','key3',1,0,1)



result_n =  df_filter (df,'key1','key2','key3',0,0,1)
```

How can I make a loop to get the results of all possible combinations of key1,key2 and key 3 using this function?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the results of `df.head().to_dict()` into your question so that we can work with a similar dataframe without having to copy your screenshot by hand

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal change that gets the job done. To get an array of results, you can add the statement `from itertools import product` and do

```
results = [df_filter(df,'key1','key2','key3',*tup) 
               for tup in product([0,1],repeat=3)]
```